# Multiple Annotations found at this line. MyConnection cannot be resolved

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I'm trying to connect this index.jsp to a database, but  have been getting this error

```
An error occurred at line: [7] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]<br>
MyConnection cannot be resolved

4: <%@ page import="com.connection.*" %><br>
5: <%
6:  Connection con = null;<br>
7:  con = MyConnection.dbCon();<br>
8:  PreparedStatement pst;<br>
9:  
10:     String id = request.getParameter("unq_id");
```

```
<%
    Connection con = null;
    con = MyConnection.dbCon();
    PreparedStatement pst;
    
    String id = request.getParameter("unq_id");
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    
    if(request.getParameter("Create Account") != null) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO student (unq_id,username,password) VAUES(?,?,?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        
        pst.setString(1, id);
        pst.setString(2, userName);
        pst.setString(3, pass);
        
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }
%>
```

Comment: Having java code in jsp is not desirable.   Try using a MVC paradigm.

Comment: Does that class imported correctly on jsp page? Also what is exact error?

Comment: The error am getting is multiple annotations on the MyConnection. dbCon();

Comment: I just started learning JSP and Servlets technology, am a beginner.